# Not signing the user in Facebook using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, json, facebook

I am trying to retrieve data data from the server. The server should return the basic information of the user when the json request is successful.

My problem is that, when i remove this code to my .plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fb***</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
```

Theres no problem aside from this warning i get from the logs:

```
FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme
```

This presents the login view to be popup:

[image]

And all the data i need to get fetched properly. but what i want is to have the login in a browser then it goes back to the app.. so i included the code above in my .plist file.

here is my code for fetching the values:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_DISPLAY_NAME_TEXT] !=nil) {}else{
    NSLog(@"@@wew: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_DISPLAY_NAME_TEXT]);
    [webService getDataFromURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_SERVER_URL, FB_URL_LOGIN]];
}
```

and this is the web service file that i am using:

```
- (void) postRequestFromUrl: (NSString *) urlString withDictionary: (NSDictionary *) post{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
NSString *  postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

//url where u will send data
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postLength length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSLog(@"@@REQUEST: %@", request);
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
}
```

This code fetch the data i needed when the login is popup. I need the user to be signed-in first so i put the request there. Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first put  openurl code in `appdelegate.m` file

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {


        return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];

}
```

then use below code for facebook login :

```
 NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_friends",nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                               allowLoginUI:TRUE
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                              if (!error) {

                                  hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
                                  hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
                                  hud.dimBackground = NO;

                                  [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
                                   ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                       if (!error) {

                                           [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture.type(large),id,birthday,email,name,gender,location" forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                                               //username
                                               if (!error) {
                                                   NSString *facebookId = user.objectID;
                                                   NSString *firstName = user.first_name;
                                                   NSString *lastName = user.last_name;
                                                   NSString *email = ([user objectForKey:@"email"] == nil) ? @"" : [user objectForKey:@"email"];

                                                  // NSString *username = (user.username == nil) ? @"" : user.username;

                                                   NSString *gender = [user objectForKey:@"gender"];
                                                   NSString *birthday = user.birthday;
                                                   NSString *userLocation = ([[user objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"name"] == nil) ? @"" : [user objectForKey:@"location"];

                                                   NSString *year = [birthday substringFromIndex:6];
                                                   NSString *monthstr = [birthday substringFromIndex:3];
                                                   NSString *month = [monthstr substringToIndex:2];
                                                   NSString *date = [birthday substringToIndex:2];

                                                   birthday = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",date,month,year];

                                                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"url"]]]];
                                                   NSData *dataImg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

                                                   userDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                                                   [userDict setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:[email RemoveNull] forKey:@"email"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:email forKey:@"username"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:dataImg forKey:@"profilephoto"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:gender forKey:@"gender"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:facebookId forKey:@"facebookId"];
                                                   [userDict setObject:userLocation forKey:@"location"];
                                                   [self performSelector:@selector(signUpUser:) withObject:userDict afterDelay:0.1];
                                               }

                                               [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

                                           }];
                                       }
                                   }];
                              }
                          }];
```

Comment: Thank you for this. sorry for late response, I'm having a hard time fixing my app.